# Json Object is null

Tags: java, android, json

I have a JsonObject based Class called JSONParse. There is this method:

```
public String getName()
    {
        try {
            JSONObject jobj = this.getJSONObject("Data");
            Log.e("NFF NAME", jobj.toString());
            JSONObject jobj2= jobj.getJSONObject("User");
            Log.e("NFF NAME", jobj2.toString());
            return jobj2.getString("username");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

The Log:

```
03-19 19:50:09.280: E/NFF NAME(5909): {"User":{"picture":"http://vm19.htl-leonding.ac.at/img/30.png","gender":"f","username":"lisa","age":32}} 
03-19 19:50:09.280: E/NFF NAME(5909): {"picture":"http://vm19.htl-leonding.ac.at/img/30.png","gender":"f","username":"lisa","age":32}
```

Problem:

This method above always returns null for the name.

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

username is inside User... try this

```
public String getName()
    {
        try {
            JSONObject jobj = this.getJSONObject("Data");
            Log.e("NFF NAME", jobj.toString());
            JSONObject jobj2= jobj.getJSONObject("User");
            Log.e("NFF NAME", jobj2.toString());
            JSONObject jobj2b= jobj2.getJSONObject("User");
            Log.e("NFF NAME", jobj2b.toString());
            return jobj2b.getString("username");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

i don't tested but you may try...

**EDITED**:
i'm sorry, i write fast and dont look at the code, jobj2b point to jobj2 first child: 'User'

Comment: What is the difference between jobj2 and jobj2b variable?

Comment: i'm sorry, i write fast and dont look at the code, jobj2b point to jobj2 first child: 'User'